# Running camera on iPhone (OS 7)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios7

I have code that perfectly works on iPad

```
self.clockInEmployee = nil;
self.clockInEmployee = [[userInfo userInfo] valueForKey:@"employee"];
self.clockInEmployeeRole = [[userInfo userInfo] valueForKey:@"role"];
CLog (@"PIN %@", self.clockInEmployee.pin);

UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
picker.delegate = (id)self;
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
picker.showsCameraControls = YES;
picker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront;
picker.cameraOverlayView = self.cameraOverlay.view;
if (isPhone())
{
    picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 748, 1024, 748);
    [mainNavController.view addSubview:picker.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [picker viewDidAppear:YES];
    }];
}
modViewController = picker;
```

but on iPhone when it try to launch camera I only observe black screen.

But if I try to launch it like that:

```
[appPresentingViewController presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

it launches successfully. But in my particular project it causes some UI problems, so it can't be used.

How can I make this

```
if (isPhone())
{
    picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 748, 1024, 748);
    [mainNavController.view addSubview:picker.view];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        picker.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 748);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [picker viewDidAppear:YES];
    }];
}
```

work for both iPad and iPhone ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:-

```
//create an overlay view instance
OverlayView *overlay = [[OverlayView alloc]
        initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGTH)];

//create a new image picker instance
UIImagePickerController *picker =
                [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
//set source to video!
picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
//hide all controls
picker.showsCameraControls = NO;
picker.navigationBarHidden = YES;
picker.toolbarHidden = YES;
//make the video preview full size
picker.wantsFullScreenLayout = YES;
picker.cameraViewTransform =
CGAffineTransformScale(picker.cameraViewTransform,
            CAMERA_TRANSFORM_X,
            CAMERA_TRANSFORM_Y);
//set our custom overlay view
picker.cameraOverlayView = overlay;

//show picker
[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
```

for further refrence -[here](http://www.jademind.com/blog/posts/ios-camera-overlay-view)

Answer (score 0):

You may like to go through apples sample project of AVCAM it can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCam/Introduction/Intro.html)

what you need to do is something like this:

```
AVCaptureSession *avcam = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *previewLayer = 
        [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:avcam];
    previewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds; 
   [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:previewLayer];
```